# Test whether a list doesn't contain a value

Tags: clojure

I have a vector with maps (each with an id) and I want to select only the maps which id **is not** in a list of ids. What's the most idiomatic way to do that?

```
(def input [{:id 1 :asd 8} {:id 2 :asd 4} {:id 3 :asd 7} {:id 4 :asd 4}])
(def connected-ids '(1 3))

;; this is what I want to get:
(def not-connected [{:id 2 :asd 8} {:id 4 :asd 4})
```

The returned collection doesn't have to be a vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion would be to

1. Keep the connected IDs in a *set*: `(def connected-ids #{1 3})`
   This step gives us both deduplication (it doesn't make sense to have an ID in the blacklist twice) *and* a handy membership test function - simply call the set as a function and it will return the (one) argument iff it is a member, else `nil`. It's also cheaper in terms of asymptotic time than scanning a list to check whether a value is in it.
2. Use [`remove`](http://conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/1.7.0/clj/clojure.core/remove/) to remove items that we don't want:

```
(def not-connected (remove (comp connected-ids :id) input))
```

Comment: A set works as an *identity function* on its members, otherwise `nil`: `(#{1 3} 1)` yields `1`, not `true`. This does not affect your argument, since anything other than `nil` and `false` is truthy.

Comment: +1
You might add to the advantages of the set that it's asymptotically more effective to check, as the list gives quadratic runtime altogether.